# From Object to Array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, methods, javascript-objects

I need to write a function that takes in an object and returns an array with this object's property values.

Ex.:

```
var obj = {
    name: "Joao",
    age: 27,
    country: "USA"
};
```

The function should return an array like this:

```
var array = ["John", 27, "USA"];
```

I can't use Object.values().

That's how my last attempt looks like:

```
function returnValues(obj) {
    for (var key in obj) {
    return obj[key];
}
```

It does not return an array with the values. Can anyone help me?

Comment: `I can't use Object.values().` yes you can - https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values#Polyfill

Answer (score 6):

You could try using map:

```js
var obj = {
    name: "Joao",
    age: 27,
    country: "USA"
};

var array = Object.keys(obj).map(item => obj[item]);

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 4):

You can either use [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) and iterate over that to return the values:

```
function returnValues(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map(function(key) {
       return obj[key];
    });
}
```

Or you can create a temp array using your existing solution:

```
function returnValues(obj) {
    var temp = [];
    for (var key in obj) {
       temp.push(obj[key]);
    }
    return temp;
}
```

With ES6 support you can shorten to:

```
const returnValues = (o) => Object.keys(o).map(k => o[k]);
```

Or use [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```
Object.entries(obj).map(([,v]) => v)
```

Or as @ibrahim mahrir points out, if you have ES2017 support you can use [`Object.values`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values):

```
console.log(Object.values(obj));
```

Comment: Thanks @ibrahimmahrir. Add ALL THE SOLUTIONS! :P

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I wish I could donate the upvote I received for this answer to you :P - updated

Comment: I'm so happy just to help!

Answer (score 2):

Add it to an array and then return the array

```
function returnValues(obj) {
    var arr = [];
    for (var key in obj)
       arr.push(obj[key]);
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `Object.entries()`.

```js
var obj = {name: "Joao", age: 27, country: "USA"},
    elems = Object.entries(obj).map(v => v[1]);

    console.log(elems);
```